# How to create parsing function with two arguments in Haskell that uses currying

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, currying

I want to create a function in Haskell that parses a 'variable' such that I consume all that is parsed up to a point at which space begins as would be the case in declaring a variable `someVar = 4` I am trying to use `endBy1`. [As seen here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#v:sepBy) however it takes `p sep` as arguments where `p` is what is to be parsed and `sep` the seperator.

Normally I would use currying when parsing, such as in

```
space :: Parser Char
space = satisfy isSpace
```

Considering that I have two arguments in the task at hand, how do I implement a function that take currying into consideration but parses `p` based on currying whereas the seperater `sep` will be determined by a fixed argument. I have tried creating the following helperfunction (the equivalent of `flip` I suspect), that I could then put in a do block to parse such as seen below:

```
helpersep :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser [a] 
helpersep sep str = sepBy str sep
```

Do block to put it in.

```
pIdent :: Parser a 
pIdent = (do 
            s <- get
            until <- (helpersep isSpace)
            return until)
```

I get the following output:

```
error:
    * Couldn't match expected type: ReadP [Char]
                  with actual type: Parser a0 -> Parser [a0]
    * Probable cause: `helpersep' is applied to too few arguments
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: until <- (helpersep isSpace)
      In the expression:
        do s <- get
           until <- (helpersep isSpace)
           if isDigit s then
               pfail
           else
               if (read (s : until)) `elem` [...] then
                   pfail
               else
                   (do rest <- many (satisfy isPrint)
                       ....)
      In an equation for `pIdent':
          pIdent
            = (do s <- get
                  until <- (helpersep isSpace)
                  if isDigit s then
                      pfail
                  else
                      if (read (s : until)) `elem` [...] then
                          pfail
                      else
                          (do rest <- many (satisfy isPrint)
                              ....))
    |
163 |             until <- (helpersep isSpace) -
```

There might be an entirely different way of working around this rather than using currying, I am however very curious to the latter approach since I suspect it will give me a better understanding of Haskell.

Comment: Currying means that `helpersep isSpace` is still a function of type `Parser a -> Parser [a]`. So it is not a parser yet and you can't use it in the do block like that.

Comment: Can I do something like this then: `helpersep (many (satisfy (\x -> isSpace x)))` (in the do block) or are you saying that their is no way around it at all?

Comment: That's still just supplying `helpersep` with a single argument, so it won't work either. I'm not sure what you actually want this to do. What is the desired behavior?

Comment: But supplying `helpersep` with just one argument is the idea of currying I would say. I want to parse all remaining letters in a word/variable after the first one such that when it reaches a space it stops parsing and assigns the parsed to a variable in the do block. I realize now that the `isSpace` should be `isLetter` but it should give some idea of what I want currying to do for me. I don't really see why you can't use it in a do block as you state.

Comment: Why use `sepBy` then? It seems to me that you don't want to parse a list of things separated by a separator at all. Instead I would just use `munch isLetter`. Or `munch1 isLetter` which allows you to leave out that first `get`.

Comment: As I stated there are no doubt other and smarter ways to work around. However I am just curious about the currying in the parsing context with two arguments and why it doesn't work if it doesn't work. And from what you write I am not sure I see that yet.

Comment: `helpersep isSpace` itself does not type-check; `isSpace :: Char -> Bool`, not `Parser a` for some type `a`. You are also using "currying" incorrectly. Currying a function of type `(a, b) -> c` means producing an isomorphic function of type `a -> b -> c`, and we call that result a curried function; that's it. Applying `helpersep` to one argument instead of two (informally speaking) is partial function application of a curried function.